# How to move focus on next element in select2

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I am trying to move focus on next element when the select change in select2. But I can't do that.
Why doesn't my focus move on to the next field?

html code

```
<form>
<select autofocus id="select2" name="entry_id">
    <option value="0">00000000</option>
    <option value="1">11111111</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="entry_id2" class="entry2">
```

javascript code

```
$("#select2").select2();
$("#select2").on("change", function () {
 $(this).closet("form").find(".entry2").focus();
});
```

Sample Page : https://jsfiddle.net/39wk54zk/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a 100% fix, but I have noticed in this piece of code, you have written .closet instead of .closest:

```
 $(this).closet("form").find(".entry2").focus();
```

I think it should be:

```
 $(this).closest("form").find(".entry2").focus();
```

I haven't tested, but this may be part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code to move focus backward or forward.

```
      let cursorDirection = ''
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        let key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            //does not matter if user has pressed tab key or not
            cursorDirection = 'prev';
        }
        else if (key == 9) {
            //if tab key is pressed then move next.
            cursorDirection = 'next';
        }
        else {
            cursorDirection == '';
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').select2({
            selectOnClose: true 
        });
        $('.select2-container').focusin(function () {
            try {
                $(this).siblings('select').select2('open');
            } catch (e) {
            }
        });
        $('select').on('select2:close', function () {
            if (cursorDirection == 'next') {
                this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.focus();
            }
            else if (cursorDirection == 'prev') {
                this.previousElementSibling.focus();
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this with tabbable.js , I had same issue which had solved

```js
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
$(function() {
  $(document).off('keydown ,select2:close', '.form-control,.select2-search__field')
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    focusable: function(el, index, selector) {
      return $(el).is('a, button, :input, [tabindex]');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('keydown ,select2:close', '.form-control,.select2-search__field', function(e) {

    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery.tabNext();
    }
  });
});
```